# Verificar se um registro veio nulo do back-end no Angular

Tags: angularjs, rest

Tenho uma modal aonde tenho dois inputs do tipo texto: `CPF` e `Senha`. No input de `CPF` tenho um `ng-blur` que faz uma Requisição `GET` toda vez que mudo de campo. Se eu digito um `CPF` que existe no banco ele fez o `GET` corretamente, porém gostaria de exibir algum alerta caso não ache o `CPF` no `back-end`.

Quando tento buscar um CPF que não existe esse é o erro que acontece no servidor:

> GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path
>   [/UnimedWS] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException: You can't
>   serialize null objects] with root cause
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: You can't serialize null objects

Como posso tratar esse erro da melhor forma possível e colocar um alerta em uma mensagem ou até mesmo um contorno vermelho no `input` do `CPF`?

Função que faz o `GET` e é passada para o `ng-blur`:

```
  $scope.getBeneficiario = function(usuario){
    loginAPI.getBeneficiario(usuario.cpf).success(function(data){
        console.log("uhul" +data);
        return loginAPI.getBeneficiario(usuario.cpf);

    })
    .error(function(response, status) {
        console.log("Resposta: "+response +"Status: "+status);

    });     
};
```

ERRO na página:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Página:

```
<div class="alinhar">
   <form name="usuarioForm">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="CPF" ng-model="usuario.cpf" ng-required="true" ng-blur="getBeneficiario(usuario)" />
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fone" placeholder="Senha" ng-model="usuario.senha" 
         ng-required="true"/>
   </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="adicionarUsuario(usuario)" ng-disabled="usuarioForm.$invalid">Salvar</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, você precisa verificar como está tratando o fator "Não encontrar nenhum registro", do lado do server.

eu utilizaria de 2 formas do lado do server.

1ª encontrou registro, retornar uma Request com Status 200 (Ok), não encontrou registro, retorna uma Request com status 412 (Pré condição falha).

do lado Client.

```
(Como não sei o que seu getBeneficiario faz).

    $http('url get benefeficiar  + cpf').then(function(retorno) { 

    if(retorno.status === 200) { // successo
       //aqui não será null

    }else{
        //aqui o retorno é o null, por que você está tratando do lado do server.
    }
} );
```

2ª caso não de para tratar do lado do server.

```
    $http('url get benefeficiar  + cpf').then(function(retorno) { 

       if(retorno.data !== null || retorno.data !== undefined){
          //Código aqui,
       }
    });
```

Comment: To mexendo aqui e fiz dessa forma:
`.error(function(response, status) {
            if(status === 500){
                console.log("Status 500")
            }
        });`

Comment: isso é valido? não trará nenhum problema futuramente, dessa forma que fiz quando o CPF é invalido ele exibe a mensagem no console, ou seja, a verificação está funcionando.

Comment: eu utilizo sempre da 1ª forma, quando programa Server e Client, assim deixo o server realizando todos os tratamentos e o client, só controlando os retornos @Techies

Comment: Entendi, aproveitando a pergunta como faço pra se cair no Else colocar um contorno vermelho o input do CPF?

Comment: se você estiver utilizando Boostrap, você pode adicionar a classe has-error, ae tem N formas de se fazer para adicionar essa classe dinamicamente ..

Comment: tem algum componente do Angular que faça isso?

Comment: Não que eu conheça .. utilizo input do html, boostrap e para fazer dinamico a alteração de classes ng-class do angular

Comment: ah n esquece, se a resposta resolveu seu problema, de marcar como resolvida ? @Techies.

Comment: Resolveu sim, agora só falta a parte do alerta, caso não consiga abro outra pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Basta você verificar o retorno de `loginAPI.getBeneficiario(usuario.cpf);`.

tente fazer da seguinte forma:

```
  $scope.getBeneficiario = function(usuario){
    loginAPI.getBeneficiario(usuario.cpf).success(function(data){
        console.log("uhul" +data);
        var res = loginAPI.getBeneficiario(usuario.cpf);
        if (res != null)
          return res;
        else return "";

    })
    .error(function(response, status) {
        console.log("Resposta: "+response +"Status: "+status);

    });     
};
```

Comment: Sim, mas como verifico esse retorno?

Comment: Você faz chamadas Ajax com retorno json certo ?

Comment: Sim, porém só não estou sabendo como verificar esse retorno. Já tentei usar promisse mas acho que não fiz certo também.

Comment: Colocar um debugger para ver o que esta retornando, assim fica fácil de saber como validar se está nulo ou não.
Se esta retornando `undefined` ou ""

Comment: Arrumei a função colocando promisse. Vou editar a pergunta com a nova função e o erro

Comment: Ok, fico feliz em conseguir ajuda-lo.

Comment: editei a pergunta e coloquei o erro que está aparecendo no console e modifiquei a função.

Comment: Alterei minha resposta para tentar ajuda-lo com o novo problema.
Me mostre o retorno de `console.log("uhul" +data);`

Comment: Retorna isso: `uhul[object Object]`

Comment: Mas no browser você pode ver o conteúdo deste Objeto, se puder enviar para ajuda-lo.

Comment: Como posso visualiza-lo, só consigo ver o resultado da requisição GET